# Index funds with dividends?

Tags: united-states, stocks, dividends, index-fund

I'm new to buying stocks. I've done a bit of reading about investing in the stock market. Some people seem to recommend index funds. Other people seem to recommend only buying stocks that pay dividends.

Those recommendations have me wondering:

1. Are there index funds for the Dow and Nasdaq?
2. Do any of those index funds pay dividends?

Comment: Typically, index funds paying dividends reinvest those dividends... or at least that's how mine are set up.

Comment: @keshlam I don't think they're allowed to do that. If they were, a lot of people would choose this option to defer taxes.

Comment: Mine do, though I do pay shortterm gains tax on the dividends. "If it happens, it must be possible."

Comment: @keshlam Ah, well that's a pretty bad deal then right, since you can't get the lower qualified dividends rate?

Comment: @Craig W: You do get the qualified dividends rate.  Your mutual fund should send you an annual IRS form 1099-DIV (if you're in the US), which separates out ordinary & qualified dividends and other relevant stuff.

Comment: @jamesqf I know, I was referring to keshlam who said they pay short-term capital gains on dividends.

Comment: @Craig W: I misunderstood, then.  But for the OP, the 1099-DIV (and 1099-B if you sell anything) should have all the info re dividends, short & long-term capital gains, foreign tax paid, and so on, so all you have to do is figure out how to get it into your F-1040 and Schedule D.

Comment: I was probably misremembering re rate... point I was making is that reinvestment is an available option in some funds. Read the prospectus for details, contact your broker (or the investment house running the fund) amd ask questions if clarification is needed.

Comment: @keshlam I think it's probably your brokerage that's reinvesting the dividends. But since you're taxed on it anyway, it's equivalent to the fund paying you dividends in cash, and then you immediately using that cash to buy more shares (with no commission and allowing fractional shares).

Comment: In my case the "brokerage" is the investment house. But yes, it's a dividend and is taxed as such  before being reinvested.

Comment: @Craig W: Why would you buy mutual funds through a brokerage, rather than directly?

Comment: @jamesqf I don't buy mutual funds, but often the brokerage _is_ the mutual fund company, e.g. Vanguard and Fidelity. For other mutual funds, I'd buy through a brokerage for convenience (assuming no transaction costs).

Comment: @Craig W: I wouldn't think of the mutual fund company as a brokerage, but that's semantics.  Can't see how going through a brokerage would be more convenient than dealing direct, though.

Comment: @jamesqf In the case of Vanguard, Fidelity, and others, they literally serve the role of both the mutual fund company and the brokerage, it's not just semantics. And using a brokerage is convenient if you only want to deal with one account, yet might want to buy mutual funds from multiple providers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Yes, for example [FNCMX](https://fundresearch.fidelity.com/mutual-funds/summary/315912709), a mutual fund tracking the Nasdaq and [IYY](https://www.ishares.com/us/products/239513/ishares-dow-jones-us-etf) and [DIA](https://www.spdrs.com/product/fund.seam?ticker=DIA), two ETFs tracking the Dow.
2. Yes, they all pay dividends because the funds are required to distribute the dividends they receive from their constituent stocks.

Answer (score -3):

I assume that when you say 'the DOW' that you actually mean the general market.

The ticker symbol for the general market is SPY (called a 'Spider'). The ticker symbol for Nasdaq is QQQ.

[SPY](http://www.marketwatch.com/investing/fund/SPY?CountryCode=US) currently pays 2.55% in dividends in a year.

[QQQ](http://www.marketwatch.com/investing/fund/QQQ?CountryCode=US) currently pays 1.34% in dividends in a year.

Comment: It is incorrect to say that the "ticker symbol for the general market is SPY (called a 'Spider')". First, the SPDR SPY tracks the S&P500 index, which is not the complete international or even US market. Also, there are other providers of S&P500 ETFs such as iShares (IVV) and Vanguard (VOO), not to mention mutual funds, so SPY is not "the market." Similarly, QQQ does not mean "the Nasdaq," it is an ETF by Powershares to track the Nasdaq 100, which is the top ~100 non-financials in the Nasdaq.

Comment: I can either be helpful to a newbie or I can be exactly, technically, correct. I chose to be helpful. @Alex, While you are technically correct, your reply is not helpful. It would only be confusing to a novice in the stock market. What Johnathan asked for was help, which I provided.

Comment: I don't think writing a misleading answer that implies things that are entirely false is helpful to newbies.  And "The Dow" has a common sense meaning, the Dow Jones Industrial Average ...

Comment: Neither Joe nor Alex have provided substantial help to a newbie (such as Johnathan). I propose we let Johnathan be the judge. Johnathan, who has been the most helpful, myself, Joe, or Alex?